# Why shell is saying unexpected token near 'fi'

Tags: shell

I am writing the script in my windows machine and later on transferring it on the host machines's linux environment.

Below is my simple script but when i am trying to run it then i am getting unexpected token near 'fi'. I have checked but there is no syntax error in my script .Please help Thanx in advance.

```
mysql --user=root --password= erpint -B -e "select * from user_info;" | sed      "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > /home/mayuri/detail.csv
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
mutt -s "Mutt attach" srini@erpint.com -a /home/mayuri/detail.csv < /home/mayuri/trials.txt
fi
```

Comment: This appears to be a part of the script.  Do you have `if` elsewhere?

Comment: No i am not using if else where in the script @devnull

Comment: I am writing the script in my windows machine and later on transferring it on the host machines's linux environment

Comment: So your problem is CRLF (essentially what @rr- mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

Check if your file's EOL style is UNIX, not Windows.